Pink heart emoji not showing on Monterey
The pink heart emoji doesn't render on my iMac with Monterey.
This emoji was introduced in Unicode 15.0 in 2022, which is after the initial release of Monterey (October 25, 2021).
Can I update the font library of my mac so that it renders? Or do I need to upgrade to Sonoma?

You need to get a copy of whatever version of the Apple Color Emoji font finally added that particular emoji and try to replace your own copy of that font with the newer one.  Even without that, you can still send that emoji to others by just copy/pasting it from another source, even if it does not display at your end.

I think you may find it in CoreEmoji.framework
